# PHP Method Not Being Executed

Tags: php

Why isn't the function `level()`being run?  I run start somewhere else in my PHP code so that is irrelevant.  I wrote `$LEVEL = level($skillxp)` however the "`cho 'efniewfb3idn3uo';` never prints out.

What is going on here?

```
function level($xp) {
    echo 'efniewfb3idn3uo';
    for ($lvl = 1; $lvl < 99; $lvl++) {
        if ($xp < experience($lvl)) {
            $lvl -= 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $lvl;
}

function experience($lvl) {
    $xp = 0;
    for($x = 1; $x < $lvl; $x++) {
        $xp += floor($x + 300 * pow(2, ($x / 7)));
    }
    return floor($xp / 4);
}

function start() {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_rows; $i++) {
        $res = $con->query("SELECT * FROM hiscores LIMIT $i, 1");
        $xp = $res->fetch_assoc();
        $skillxp = $xp['0'];
        $LEVEL = level($skillxp);
        echo 'efniewfb3idn3uo';
//return $LEVEL = level($skillxp);
}
}
```

Comment: None of your methods are being called? Why would the execute?

Comment: And where is you definition for `$num_rows` inside the `start()` function?

Comment: Enable `error_reporting` and notices to find out why your loop never runs.

Comment: Where is start() being called?

Comment: Also, you are missing a `}` in the function `start()`.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr is right, though hopefully you just forgot a line there when you copied and pasted it, or you would've seen an error rather than something not running.

Comment: I have the bracket in my code.  Didn't copy completely.

Comment: Start is being called here: http://pastebin.com/VqE4j1DA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not declaring `$num_rows` before the `for`, so your `for` loop never runs. You need either set that at the start of the function or pass it in as a parameter.

Just to be clear, you had the right idea, using `echo` to test. However, you want to `echo` actually relevant variables too when you see a problem like this.

Even with the link you posted to your full code, you're defining `$num_rows` outside of the scope of the function. You would need to call `$num_rows` from within your function using `global`, but that's not generally recommended unless you're sure `$num_rows` is always the same. Even then, why not just set it in the function or pass it in consistently?

For more information, here are the [PHP docs on variable scope.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: I am sorry for leaving out code.  Here is the full code.  I do declare $num_rows.  Code here:  http://pastebin.com/CkWxSdeU  By the way, the start function runs, the for loop as well.  I've used echo to test it.

Comment: I edited my answer with that in mind.

Comment: Yes.... but the for loop in the start function is running, I tested it with echo.  for the second time. My question is: WHY ISN'T LEVEL RUNNING?  I'm sorry if I seem aggravated, it's just that, nobody has given me a straight answer within the many questions I've asked regarding PHP.  I've spent 3 days straight on this program and this is just one more barrier, and I really really really need a straight and direct answer in laymans terms for once.  Please man.

Comment: How can you tell the difference? You're using the same string to test.

Comment: Also, your question stated that the `echo` string never prints out, so this isn't for the second time. I want to help, but you need to be clear in your question to get a clear answer.

Comment: Alright, I did what you said exactly.  And it worked.  The level method is now being run.  However, it messed up my for loop. http://pastebin.com/xuPEjh6u  For some reason the data being sent is not being changed by the $i variable.  It's the same number each time.  It was different before I added the scope inside the function.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40228/discussion-between-evan-and-nic)